# Has anybody written a Spark data source proxy/factory?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datasource

I would like to find a Spark custom data source implementation which itself simply selects from and returns some existing data source implementation, based on dynamic configuration. For example, given an arbitrary configuration key "MyDataSource", in one case it may return a Parquet data source, and in another case it may return an Avro data source, depending on the configuration files at runtime.

Has anybody already done this?

Comment: How would you like to use that proxy? Can you provide an example? i.e  could it be something like `spark.read.myDataSource(sourceType, path)` sourceType -> {parquet|avro}?

Comment: I would use it like this: spark.format("my-data-source").read("my-data"). Whether my-data comes from Parquet, or Redshift, or XYZ is not evident and is not known until runtime. "my-data" is a key into a configuration, which selects the data source type.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement a datasource, you can create this logic in the driver to choose the format to read. For example:

```
val sparkSession = ...

trait Source

case class Parquet(path: String) extends Source
case class Jdbc(url: String, port: Int) extends Source

def readSource(s: Source)(spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = s match {
  case Parquet(path) => spark.read.parquet(path)
  case Jdbc(url, port) => ...
}

val aSourceFromConfig: Source = ...

val df: DataFrame = readSource(aSourceFromConfig)(spark)
```

Comment: Of course I do not need a data source, but I asked for a data source. My question is not, how can I choose a format. My question is, has somebody implemented such a datasource? But thank you for the response.